# create folder name base on partial file name

Tags: powershell

i have file names that have a "-" (hyphen) in the filename.  I am trying to create a folder for each filename and move the file to the folder.

here is what I am trying to use:

```
dir | %{ 
    $id = $_.Name.SubString(0,5); 
    if(-not (Test-Path $id)) {mkdir $id}; 
    mv $_ "$id\$_";}
```

The issue is, some of the file names have less than 5 characters before the hyphen, so for those folders the hyphen is being added to the folder name.  I've tried to use the Split verbiage, but I am stuck on syntax.

a couple of filenames examples are below:

- A1909-6628.txt
- A963-6634.txt

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
#split return an array
$id = ($_.Name -split '-')[0];
```

Comment: well, other than missing the parenthesis and using a -1 in quotes at the end, I was close

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much on the right track, and you've mentioned the [-split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7.1) operator which is all you really need.

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $id = $_.BaseName.split('-')[0];
        if((Test-Path $id) -eq $false){Mkdir $id}
            Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $id 
                }
```

Without modifying your code too much, i added the split at the hyphen then selectin the first value after the split.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -file -filter "*-*" | %{

#extract first part of file
$Part1=($_.BaseName -split '-')[0].Trim()

#create directory if exist
$NewFolderName="{0}\{1}" -f $_.DirectoryName, $Part1 
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $NewFolderName -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#prepare new filename
$NewPathFile="{0}\{1}" -f $NewFolderName, $_.Name

#move file into new directory
Move-Item $_.FullName $NewPathFile

}
```